# `oversized data {"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true} ProviderError: oversized data`

Tags: nft, hardhat, error

I am trying to deploy a NFT smart contract which takes 1 parameter that is an array of length 8912. The problem is the array length. I have tested with an array of length 100 and it works perfectly but not with length 8912. But array max size on Solidty is 2^256, so i dont know why it is not working.

The content of the array are just ipfs links for the NFT metadata (8912 links). Because of the design of the contract, it is contract to pass the links of the metadata of each NFT. The idea is that a user can mint a selected NFT for example the NFT with Id 5000 and it has its corresponding metadata, thats why i am trying to pass the metadata to the Smar Contract constructor.

- `deploy script`:

```bash
const args = [tokenUris, tokenUris.length, networkConfig[chainId]["threshold0"], networkConfig[chainId]["threshold1"], networkConfig[chainId]["threshold2"], networkConfig[chainId]["threshold3"], networkConfig[chainId]["mintFee_type0"], networkConfig[chainId]["mintFee_type1"], networkConfig[chainId]["mintFee_type2"], networkConfig[chainId]["mintFee_type3"], networkConfig[chainId]["mintFee_type4"]]
    const MetaStarNFTV1 = await deploy("Contract", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
        gasLimit: 153555690000,
    })
```

- `hardhat.config.js`:

```bash
mumbai: {
      url: POLYGON_MUMBAI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
      saveDeployments: true,
      chainId: 80001,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
      gas: 1535556900,
      gasPrice: 8000000000
    },
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: false,
    outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
    noColors: true,
    currency: "USD",
    coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: POLYSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
    user_1: {
      default: 1,
    },
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 200000, // 200 seconds max
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.7" }, { version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.6.6" }],
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 100
      }
    }
  },
```